# Laravel 4 multiple sites with single codebase

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-4

With Codeigniter it's quite simple to run multiple sites using the same framework codebase, so that when you update the framework, you only have to do it in one place. Does anybody have a "how to" to do the same with Laravel 4? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just duplicate the public folder and rename it to anything you want.

The trick here is to point your domains to the different public folders you renamed into. This  enables you to have the same backend with multiple sites.

Then, the next thing you need to configure is your `routes.php`. That's it.

Comment: That doesn't work because you set the application URL in the app/config/app.php file. To clarify, I want to use the same codebase, with different applications so that when I update Laravel I only have to update it in one place.

Comment: Have any of you tried this? This seems like a valid approach. Simply because L4 can handle multi-domain based routes.